# Exception when setting OracleParameter to DbType.DateTimeOffset

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter p;
// create p
p.DbType = DbType.DateTimeOffset
```

This is throwing:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException   HResult=0x80131502
>   Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess   StackTrace:    at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.set_DbType(DbType
>   value)    at
>   WindwardReportsDrivers.net.windward.datasource.ado.AdoQueryHelper.setParameter(IDbCommand
>   cmd, Int32 varNum, Object item) in
>   C:\git\Jen_2\engine\DotNetEngine\WindwardReportsDrivers\net\windward\datasource\ado\AdoQueryHelper.cs:line
>   522

Any idea what/why this is happening?